# Multiple NSTimers issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have sub-classed a component (it looks like circle and there is a picture inside it (NSView subclass)).

I want to change the picture every X time (to make it look like an animation).

When in my main view controller I drawing 1 sub-class like this everything works Fine, but when I adding more the picture changes much faster with each.

(I am firing the picture change using an `NSTimer`)
I am assuming that the issue happens because I have multiple `NSTimers` on the same queue

However I tried to use

```
NSTimer *uiTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:(1.0 / 5.0) target:self selector:@selector(changePicture) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];      
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:uiTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

It didn't solve the issue (I assume because it is still on the main thread)
So I came up with `NSThread` Solution

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateModel) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


- (void) updateModel
  {

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:secondsBetweenUpdates 
                                    target:self 
                                    selector:@selector(changePicture) 
                                    userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    }
```

It has a bit different behaviour (but still no luck as more sub-classes I have as faster picture changes).

My last shoot was this solution:

```
// Update the UI 5 times per second on the main queue
// Keep a strong reference to _timer in ARC
_timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0,     dispatch_get_main_queue());
dispatch_source_set_timer(_timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (1.0 / 5.0) * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(_timer, ^{
[self changePicture];
});

// Start the timer
dispatch_resume(_timer);
```

I am not usually giving up , but I am trying to resolve it for 3 days already... And I think I need and advice of how to do this so it will work as intended.

Comment: On you last solution, what is calling that block of code?

Comment: It was inside mySubClass `initWithFrame` method , where I am normaly initing the `NSTimers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GCD I would recommend you use `dispatch_after`, for example:

```
float delayTime = 0.2f;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                             (int64_t)(delayTime * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
               dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self changePicture];
});
```

Comment: This will perform the task after the delay , can you explain why will it help me ?

Comment: I undertand you want to execute `changePicture` after a delay (that you will repeate), so this may help you. Having said that this probably does not cover the whole picture. From your code I see you are using `NSThread`, so maybe the issue is somewhere around there. As a disclamer I have never used the `dispatch_source`functions and having read about them I still don't understand them, so I can't advice you on those. Your problem does not seem to be as complicated as your code makes it to be, so using `dispatch_async` for your background work and `dispatch_after` for the delay should work.

Comment: You mean to put a delay inside the `dispatch async` block.
and still to have an `NSTimer` to call that ?

Comment: Not quite, I meant do the background work inside a `dispatch_async` block and have `dispatch_after` or `dispatch_source` timer inside it, so no NSTimer.

Comment: Then how will it get repeated every 0.2 seconds ?

Comment: If you use your `dispatch_source` solution it will get repeated, if you used `dispatch_after` you will need to call the method wrapping `dispatch_after` again at the end of the block.

Comment: So I should add this in to my last solution? Giving it a try :)

Comment: Something is wrong with my dispath_source it doesn't work, the function oesn't trigger

Comment: Can you update your answer with the wrapping function solution example ?

Comment: I tried it thanks for help, but i have the same behaviour :(
maybe I should try to use gifs ?

Comment: I have not done any animations for mac development so I have to say that I've run out of ideas to help with. Maybe you could search or ask a new question about how would you implement an animation using cocoa.

Comment: I tried Gif and it works Fine  :) Thank you for attempt to help :)